# repeater checkbox oncheckchanged

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, repeater

I have a repeater Control and each item has a checkbox on it. I can't figure out how to use the OnCheckedChange event for this checkbox.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptImageList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptImages_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptImages_ItemCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Table runat="server" BorderStyle="None" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100%" GridLines="Both">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="3%">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%#((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsSelected")!=null) && ((bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsSelected")==true)) %>' OnCheckedChanged="cbSelect_CheckedChanged" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
        protected void rptImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            var cbSelect = e.Item.FindControl("cbSelect") as CheckBox;                
        }
    }

    protected void cbSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

How can I be able to use the state of the checkbox in the cbSelect_CheckedChanged event?
I want it when checked changed to change it's assigned BIT field in the database!

Answer (score 1):

You can created methods to handle checked changes and the sender as CheckBox will send the correct checkbos to your handler method.

```
private void Checked_Handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HandleChecked(sender as CheckBox);
}
```

You can also use the [HandleChecked and HandleUnchecked Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221404(v=vs.95).aspx)

From the docs:

```
private void HandleCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    if (cb.Name == "cb1")
        text1.Text = "Two state CheckBox checked.";
    else
        text2.Text = "Three state CheckBox checked.";
}

private void HandleUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    if (cb.Name == "cb1")
        text1.Text = "Two state CheckBox unchecked.";
    else
        text2.Text = "Three state CheckBox unchecked.";
}

private void HandleThirdState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    text2.Text = "Three state CheckBox indeterminate.";
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<!-- two state CheckBox -->
<CheckBox x:Name="cb1" Content="Two State CheckBox" 
      Checked="HandleCheck" Unchecked="HandleUnchecked" Margin="5" />
<TextBlock x:Name="text1" Margin="5" />

<!-- three state CheckBox -->
<CheckBox x:Name="cb2" Content="Three State CheckBox" 
    IsThreeState="True" Checked="HandleCheck" 
    Indeterminate="HandleThirdState" Unchecked="HandleUnchecked" Margin="5" />
<TextBlock x:Name="text2" Margin="5" />
```

Comment: I tried that but it says "The name Checked does not exist in the current context" and I cant use cbSelect.Checked because it is a repeater control, have to call it some other way but how?

Comment: It underlines the "RoutedEventArgs" and says the type or namespace name could not be found and doesn't suggest to add a library